# Install WSDL in Salesforce?

Tags: integration, wsdl

client provides wsdl file and says to install it into sandbox. I know I can download wsdl from salesforce to create external applications but I've never heard of installing a wsdl into salesforce. Where do I go to acoomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup -> Develop -> Apex -> Generate from WSDL

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm

A quick google search yields the official documentation